# Group query result based on expired date time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Orders Table with an Order Date Time Field, I want to grouping the result by before and after today order date. and after that I want to sort the order after today by cusmtomer id ASC and sort the order before today by customer id DESC.

The Orders Table looks like the following image:

[image: table orders]

I tried query order before and after today and I combine the result using `UNION` but still not getting the result like what I want

I was tried query separately both of order before and after today. like this following code:

First I query the order after today like this:

```
select OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
from Orders
WHERE OrderDate > GETDATE() AND ShipCountry = 'USA'
ORDER BY CustomerID ASC
```

and the result look like this:

[image: query result order after today]

and then I query again like this:

```
select OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
from Orders
WHERE OrderDate < GETDATE() AND ShipCountry = 'USA'
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
```

and the result look like this:

[image: query result order before today]

but I don't know how to joining both of two query result above with single query instead of separately query.

What I expect in my query result is combination of before today query result and after today query result.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Or, even better, DDL and DML statements. You'll find very few users are going to transcribe your data.

Comment: Sure, I was created sample Fiddle please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ebca2/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Split the `order by` into 2 parts:

```
select OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
from Orders
WHERE  ShipCountry = 'USA'
ORDER BY
 (CASE WHEN OrderDate < GETDATE() 
   THEN CustomerID 
    END) DESC 
,   (CASE WHEN OrderDate > GETDATE() 
   THEN CustomerID 
    END) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you verry much. It's work 100% like what I want..Thanks Shikhar Arora

Answer (score 0):

**Old Ans..**

```
  select OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
    from Orders
    WHERE OrderDate <> GETDATE() AND ShipCountry = 'USA'
    ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
```

> Note:- use is not Equal to Operator for this..then you will get the
>   all result other than today date...

**New Ans...**

As you told ...you can use Order by Clause with UNION.....you need to set top records...

```
SELECT orders1.OrderID,orders1.CustomerID, orders1.OrderDate, orders1.ShipName, orders1.ShipCountry FROM
(    
SELECT TOP 100 OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
from Orders
WHERE OrderDate > GETDATE() AND ShipCountry = 'USA'
ORDER BY CustomerID ASC
)orders1

UNION 

SELECT orders2.OrderID, orders2.CustomerID, orders2.OrderDate, orders2.ShipName,orders2.ShipCountry FROM
(
SELECT TOP 100 OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCountry
from Orders
WHERE OrderDate < GETDATE() AND ShipCountry = 'USA'
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
)orders2
```

Comment: This is very likely to return every row. `GETDATE()` returns the current date and time accurate to 1/300th of a second (as `datetime` is accurate of 1/300th of a second). Unless the the OP runs this code at the exact same moment every row won't have a value of `GETDATE()`

Comment: Hi akhilesh singh. Thanks for your help. but this query not give me the result like what I expected

Comment: I was tried using `UNION` but it's getting error because I need to `ORDER` field `CustomerID` in first query `ASC` and   second query `DESC`

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The OP wants to sort the rows and this has no `ORDER BY` for the outermost `SELECT`.  Hence, the results are not guaranteed to be in any order.  I also see nothing in the question about limiting the number of rows.

Comment: @akhileshsingh  When I tried with your new answer the query does'nt ordered the customer id like what I want. Thanks for your help akhileshsingh